# How can I write a list of notations with the \hfill command and the possibility to go to a new line?

Tags: listings, lists, scientific-notation, hfill

I wrote a list of notations with the following rough code:

```
$B(x_0, r)$\hfill the open ball $\{x\in\R^d:|x-x_0|<r\}$
\par\smallskip\noindent
$\BUC(E)$\hfill the space of bounded and uniformly continuous functions on $E\subseteq\R^n$
```

What tex produces is the following one:

[image]

I would like to have `$E\subseteq\mathbb R^n$` aligned with *the space of bounded and uniformly...*. How can I do that?

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I think that a mwe is not necessary to my case. I just asked for a way to do an alignment in a listing.

Comment: the question is not if the mwe is *necessary* but if it makes it easier to test an answer and so more probable that someones takes the time to answer. Don't use \hfill but e.g. a description list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can use an xltabular (a combination of tabularx with variable-width-columns and longtable which allows tables to break across pages, but page-breaks won't break table-cells) with a p-column whose content is a `varwidth`-environment which in turn via  `\raggedleft` is shifted to the right:

```latex
% \errorcontextlines=10000
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, xltabular, varwidth, blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{%
  >{%
     \raggedleft
     \begin{varwidth}[t]{#1}%
%     \narrowragged
% This allows more hyphenation:
%     \hyphenpenalty=50
%     \exhyphenpenalty=50
%     \doublehyphendemerits=50
% This forbids hyphenation:
%     \hyphenpenalty=10000
%     \exhyphenpenalty=10000
% This will shift lines inside the varwidth to the right:
%     \raggedleft
     \let\newline\\%
     \arraybackslash
   }%
  p{#1}%
  <{%
     \@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\end{varwidth}%
   }%
}
\makeatother


\DeclareMathOperator\BUC{BUC}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\noindent text \hfill text

% Play with \arraystretch to adjust the vertical distance
% between table-rows:
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\noindent
% [l] = longtable-property
% {\textwidth} = total width of table is textwidth
% {@{}p{.2\textwidth}XR{.7\textwidth}@{}} = column-specifiers:
%    @{} - no horizontal gap at the left of the leftmost-column
%    p{.2\textwidth} - a column consisting of \parboxes of width .2\textwidth
%    X - a column whose width is calculated so that total width of table is achieved
%    R{.7\textwidth} - raggedright-varwidth-column of maximum-width .7\textwidth
%    @{} - no horizontal gap at the right of the rightmost-column
\begin{xltabular}[l]{\textwidth}{@{}p{.2\textwidth}XR{.7\textwidth}@{}}
$B(x_0, r)$&&the open ball $\{x\in\R^d:|x-x_0|<r\}$\\
$\BUC(E)$&&the space of bounded and uniformly continuous functions on $E\subseteq\R^n$
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like the word "functions" to be hyphenated, then activate the lines under "This forbids hyphenation:" and the result will look like this:

[image]